# How can I update the text in a loaded SWF file with javascript/AS3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript-3

I need to build a live preview in Flash which will show a user a customised version of a product - for example with their own text on the site.  I don't use Flash normally but understand a little bit of Actionscript 3.

I am using jQuery to embed and communicate with my SWF.  I have a SWF movie to which I am passing an initial value via a Flashvar and this shows up with the custom text in my movie.  (I create the text field in the movie with Actionscript 3)

How can I then use javascript to later send updated values for my Flashvars to the movie - for example when the customer changes the text in an input field on the HTML page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define your own function to change the textbox, and make it available to your javascript by using `ExternalInterface`.

It goes something like this:

```
class MyClass {

  static function main() {      
    if (flash.external.ExternalInterface.available) {
      flash.external.ExternalInterface.addCallback("updateText", updateText);
    }

    static function updateText(txt) {
      // Whatever you want
    }
  }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the option of [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) as the above poster has shown.

If your requirements are a little more complicated then you can use the Adobe provided [Flex Ajax Bridge](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ajaxbridge_3.html). You'll also need the Flex SDK (see [About the Flex Ajax Bridge](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ajaxbridge_1.html)).  The bridge can simplify things if you want to drive most of the SWF behaviour from JavaScript. ExternalInterface is more useful for simple, quick, one-off function calls.